# How to simplify GPIO configuration of esp32 in python?

Tags: python, esp32, simplify

Another simplify question. How can I simplify this. I was searching in the internet for the machine module but there wasn't shown that I can configure more than one GPIO per line. I think it should be possible to configure all the GPIOs in one line but I just don't know how. The GPIOs are from an esp32. And don't blame me now for my name settings (GND_X) it is not finished now so still changeable. :-)

```
from machine import Pin
GND_1 = Pin(15, Pin.OPEN_DRAIN)
GND_2 = Pin(2, Pin.OPEN_DRAIN)
GND_3 = Pin(4, Pin.OPEN_DRAIN)
GND_4 = Pin(5, Pin.OPEN_DRAIN)
GND_5 = Pin(18, Pin.OPEN_DRAIN)
GND_6 = Pin(19, Pin.OPEN_DRAIN)
GND_7 = Pin(21, Pin.OPEN_DRAIN)
```

Thank you very much for your help and your solutions!

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in a module:

```
import sys

module = sys.modules[__name__]

for idx, pin in enumerate([15, 2, 4]):
    setattr(module, 'GND_%s' % idx, Pin(pin, Pin.OPEN_DRAIN))
```